# using date count and date diff in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select dates from a table and get a day count.

Basically, if the date value in the column is greater than 180 days ago, I just want to return 180. However, if it's less than 180 days ago then I want the day count.

180 is the max that should be returned but right now I'm getting incorrect numbers.

This query

```
select 
     case when p.start_date >= (curdate() - interval 180 day) then 180 
          when p.start_date <= (curdate()-interval 180 day) then DATEDIFF(curdate(),p.start_date) end
from table;
```

Returns  540 as the count for 2017-04-14 and 180 for 2018-07-20, but I should get 180 and 78 respectively.

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Calculate number of days difference using [`Datediff()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function.
- Using [`Least()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) function, you can find the minimum value out of 180 and the difference in number of days. If the difference is more than 180, it will return 180; else the difference.

Try the following:

```
SELECT LEAST(180, DATEDIFF(curdate(), p.start_date)) 
FROM table
```

Comment: @Whisou138 happy to help :)